# Showing Totals for a Formula

Tags: joined-reports

I have a joined report. One report shows calls made, the other shows appointments. I want to display: 'accounts with a call and an appointment'/'total calls made'. I have this formula called #calls w appts:

`IF(IF(B0#Activity.Account.Name:UNIQUE = B1#Activity.Account.Name:UNIQUE,1,0)=1,B0#RowCount,0)`

where B1 is calls and B0 is appointments. I can get it to show me 1's on the rows themselves but they won't total at the bottom of the column. Can anyone help me understand why it's doing this?
[image]